# Simple AJAX request to controller - Symfony3

Tags: ajax, symfony

I use Symfony3 with PhpStorm.2016.3.2 on Ubuntu16.04

I never done an AJAX request before and would like to test a call to controller from a view->to the controller->that sends an answer back to the view in JSON.

So I read on the doc but they are all very specific. So my desire is to only being able to write a simple AJAX request in a view`(index.html.twig)`,for testing it, make a call to the controller`(MainController.php)` and return the answer in `JSON` in the view.

This is my view:

```
{% extends 'app/layout.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}
```

My controller:

```
class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('app/main/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

I really don't want to make the job done by the others, I just want to get a hint of how to make it work. So I'm sorry if my ticket is rather empty but maybe it can help others too, like me, to know where to start off.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

At first you need to register the route to your controller:

```yaml
app_bundle_route:
    path:     /ajax_request
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Main:index }
```

Then load jQuery in your main view, perhaps you've done it already. You need a call to action in your template, some trigger to beginn the AJAX request:

```
{% extends 'app/layout.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    <button class="ajax">click me!</button>
    <div id="ajax-results">here comes the result</div>
    <script>
        $(document).on('click', 'button.ajax', function(){
            that = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url:'{{ (path('app_bundle_route')) }}',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    "some_var_name": "some_var_value"
                },
                async: true,
                success: function (data)
                {
                    console.log(data)
                    $('div#ajax-results').html(data.output);

                }
            });
            return false;

        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

And at least your controller is very simple:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    if($request->request->get('some_var_name')){
        //make something curious, get some unbelieveable data
        $arrData = ['output' => 'here the result which will appear in div'];
        return new JsonResponse($arrData);
    }

    return $this->render('app/main/index.html.twig');
}
```

I think this concept should make clear how it can work

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will apply that to my work right away and letting you know how does that work (in an hour or so)
Alos I should not use the `if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())` for AJAX request? I thought so...

Comment: You can, its up to you how you match the request. I showed one of many options.

Comment: Ok thank you :) I will try that right away and letting you know.

Comment: Hm it is not really working :/ I tried with a var like this data: `{ "$test": "hello world" }`, and also the url is not url:`{{ (path('ajax_request')) }}`, I think, I used `(path('app_bundle_route'))` to match it. But I can't make it work actually. @Rawburner

Comment: your data should be like { "test": "hello world" } (without "$"). Can you please observe the resultet html code with browser developer tools and tell me what url ist beeing placed?

Comment: I took off the $ and wrote exactly like you. But when I click on the button nothing really happens. I checked with my browser tool if there is any errors and there is one in `js`. It says `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` also the URL is `localhost:8000/`

Comment: the you have not implemented jQuery yet. See https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667620/JQuery-A-Quick-Start-Guide

Comment: I install Jquerry globally, I thought that would worked. I will follow your link and apply it to see if that is the issue

Comment: make a small test in same view to ensure that jquery is enabled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135692/discussion-between-rawburner-and-criss-cross).

Comment: Don't forget `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;` in the controller.

Comment: My current project is structured exactly like your example, but i have an issue. I want to migrate all the JS into .js files and include them in the view. But that section of the ajax url:'{{ (path('app_bundle_route')) }}' which is working in the html twig cannot be resolved in the .js file.. I was wondering if there was a workaround to be able to migrate the js into dedicated js files or if i was stuck with letting the js in the views ? The first option is obviously a cleaner approach to me but might be wrong for symfony (i'm new to it) ?

Comment: Thats simple. Add the url to the button with data-tag: <button class="ajax" data-url="{{ (path('app_bundle_route')) }}">click me!</button> then you can get it with url:that.data('url'),

Comment: you should encode your response by _json_encode($arrData)_ or you'll get an empty object-prototype. well, at least I got it in symfony 3.4.17 using the given code. besides, it works like a charm.

Comment: If I return a JsonResponse then there is no need to json_encode