# Load a part of page in symfony 3 directory from jquery

Tags: jquery, symfony, load

I use Symfony and I have an element in web/getTable.php file I'd like to load. The code of this element is here:

```html
<p id="hello">Hello World!!!</p>
```

How can I get it? Before posting this,I've tried this:

```js
$('#btn').click(function(){
$('span').load("{{asset('getTable.php #hello')}}");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">load</button>
<span id="#test"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach might be to load it normally in a hidden span, and then when the button is clicked, you just make the span visible. If its long loading or you don't want to preload it, you have to do an actual Ajax call ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42221356/simple-ajax-request-to-controller-symfony3)) and build the HTML. It would of course be better to use CSS for the display:none, but this should be the basics to get it working.

Html:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">     </script>
<button id="btn">load</button>
<span id="#test" style="display:none">{{asset('getTable.php #hello')}}</span>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('span').show();
});
```

Comment: I've tried it and It shows the path to "getTable.php #hello". I'd like to get the text "Hello World!!!".

Comment: @Tsiresgrammeur What exactly is the contents of getTable.php? I assumed you were rendering the HTML in a controller action? I have never seen asset used to load a php file. Usually its for images and such, but it could just be a usage I am not familiar with.

Comment: In reality, I want to load php file in order not to refresh every instant when I go to a menu. If I use twig, that's not the case. As I said in my question, there is an element in the getTable.php file: <p id="hello">Hello World!!!</p>. The getTable.php get all contents in my database, but in the place of this element, I'll replace it to a comboBox  which contains all contents in a table in my database

Answer (score 0):

```
the really content of getTable.php is this

    

    //this is in my twig file
    <script>
        $('btn').click(function(){
        $('#test').load("{{asset('getTable.php #list')}}");
        });
    
    
    
     </script>
    //in the getTable.php file
  <table>
    <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Nombre de Place Libre</th>
    <th>Nombre de Place Exigé</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php
$bdd=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gestion_ressources_humaines', 'root','');

$reponse=$bdd->query('SELECT id, type, nbPlaceLibre, nbPlaceExige FROM fonction');

while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
{
?>
  <tr>
    <td style="display:none;"><?php echo $donnees['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $donnees['type']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $donnees['nbPlaceLibre']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $donnees['nbPlaceExige']; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php
}

?>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php
$reponse->closeCursor(); // Termine le traitement de la requête

?>
<script>
$(function(){
  $("tr").click(function(){
  $('tr').removeClass('selected');
if($(this).hasClass('selected'))
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
else
  $(this).addClass('selected');
        });
        });

</script>
    
    <p id="hello">Hello world!!!</p>
```