# How to call symfony function in controller with ajax?

Tags: ajax, symfony, twig

I want to call a function in my controller with ajax

I m really beginner and i don't really understand what i need to do

```
/**
 * @Route("/Article/{id}/{vote}", name="article_vote")
 */
public function vote($idArticle, $vote, Request $request, ObjectManager $manager){ 
}


 <script>
        $(document).on('click', '.ajax', function(){
            that = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url:'{{ (path('don't know')) }}',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Please edit your questions and add more code (the functions annotations).

Comment: I do this but i think its a little bit useless because i want to transform this -> on a function withtout routing and how to call this on twig then

Comment: Why do you want to remove routing?

Comment: Because i doesn't want to change page or reset this page / its a function like the vote we have here on stackoverflow for upvoting an article

Comment: It is not obvious what's the effect of 'voting' - I guess you are looking for an AJAX call or an update to the database?

Comment: Its an update in my database. in parameter of my function we have $vote he can be = -1 or 1. and i update the article in the database with   `$articleVote->setVotes($articleVote->getVotes() + $vote);` . I edited what i have before. i think it will be more clearly. 
Anyway, the line before its just to find the article in my database with id i unter in the parameter of my function

Comment: You have 2 options: Let the template as it is and return in controller a redirection to article detail page. The vote function will place the vote and send user back to article page. The vote action can place a flash message, which you can show on the article page. Second option is to call the action with ajax. Catch the click on the button and do an ajax call, there are many more tutorials on how to do that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42221356/simple-ajax-request-to-controller-symfony3/42221911#42221911

Comment: I don't want to refresh the page. So i think what i want is a function with ajax

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally the path of my function needed to be on **url :**

And i add a sucess and error function

```
{% block javascripts %} 
 <script>
$(document).on('click', '#ajax', function(){
   that = $(this);
  $.ajax({
       url : '{{ path('post_like', {'id' : article.id}) }}',
       type : 'POST',
       dataType : 'html',
       success : function(code_html, statut){ 
         code = JSON.parse(code_html);
     },
       error : function(resultat, statut, erreur){
       }
    });
    return false;
});

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

and i needed to add a return json

```
/**
 * @Route("/article/{id}/like", name="post_like")
 */
public function vote(Article $article, Request $request, ObjectManager $manager, ArticleLikeRepository $likeRepo) : Response {
    return $this->json([
        'code' => 200,
        'likes' => $likeRepo->count(['article' => $article])], 200);
}
```

Comment: Can you share more details? How does this work without routing?

Comment: It was just a error. At the begining was thinking i need to call a function without routing for call with ajax.